# open new TCPDF after form post

Tags: php, post, tcpdf

I have a form, test.html, (create in JS using dhtmlx, unimportant) that I want to submit to a PHP script, generateReport.php

generateReport.php creates a PDF using the information posted from the test.html using the TCPDF libraries.

How can I post the variables from test.html, and have the page redirect to the filled in PDF? I would prefer not to store it, but that really is not a problem if I store it temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

Try to post the form to generateReport.php by using form action.

And Just get all you form values by using  [$_POST](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp)['form_field_name']

I think this will help you to get all form values.